# how to clear all files like json files and images it comes with the iOS app on update?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, caching, nsbundle

my iOS application has some json files in its bundle ,, i've updated these files and upload to the store , but when updated the old json files data is still shows up , the only solution i found is to delete the app and install it again 
but its not a good solution to send to all users

so is there any way to it programtically or any other way

P.S : i tried to change the name of the json files , but its start to crash because the app can't see the path resource of the bundle with the new name
here is my code to call these files

```
{
 NSString* aFileName = @"Models.json";

NSString * fileDocumentPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [self getDocumentsDirectoryPath], aFileName];

NSFileManager * fileMngr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSString * file = [aFileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".json" withString:@""];

 NSString * sourcePath =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file ofType:@"json"];

 NSError *error;
 [fileMngr copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:fileDocumentPath error:&error];
}

-(NSString *) getDocumentsDirectoryPath {
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    documentsDirectoryPath = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];

    return documentsDirectoryPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one thing , before copying the file just check if the file exist , if exist then delete the file and then copy the new file.
This should solve your issue.

Check below link for deleting files
[How do I delete a file in my apps documents directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204916/how-do-i-delete-a-file-in-my-apps-documents-directory)

[Delete specified file from document directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017902/delete-specified-file-from-document-directory)

Regards,
Anil

Comment: great but how can i delete the file ?

Comment: To delete file : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204916/how-do-i-delete-a-file-in-my-apps-documents-directory

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([fileMngr fileExistsAtPath:fileDocumentPath isDirectory:NO]) {
    [fileMngr removeItemAtPath:fileDocumentPath error:nil];
}

 [fileMngr copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:fileDocumentPath error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
   func deleteFile(_ filePath:URL) {
        guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) else {
            return
        }
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: filePath.path)
        } catch {
            print("Unable to delete file.")
        }
    }

    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first! + "namefile.json")
    deleteFile(fileURL)
```